# php why get null json when request done by mobile app but retrieve correct data on web browser

Tags: php, json

[image: this is a snapshot of the code which encode age array using json]

this is a snapshot of the code which encode age array using json but it doesn't work well when request from mobile app it retrieve null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try to reach the solution and eventually i found that the error was because of the first line in php code page before php tag was empty ! so when i return a json it gives me  null because of the empty line